# Splitting an 8-bit Byte and assigning to a 7x1 array in Arduino

Tags: arrays, arduino, serial-port, byte, bit

I'm using a `Teensy 3.2` and `Teensyduino` to read in a `UART` signal consisting of `6 bytes` of data.
For each byte, I'd like to assign each of the bits a position in a 1x7 Array.
For example, let's say I read in the 1st byte = `01110101`. I would like an array that excludes the most significant bit(0) and looks like this
`1110101`

Below is what I've written to read the data and it works like a charm. It's the values currently stored in each element of `byteArray` that I would like to manipulate into a separate `array` as described.

I've searched high and low so if you could point me in the right direction I'd be forever grateful. I don't necessarily just want the answer, but I have no idea how to move forward at the moment. Is there a way to index specific bits in a byte that's similar to indexing positions in an Array?

```
#define PEESerial Serial2
byte byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4, byte5, byte6;
unsigned long period;
byte byteArray[6];
int count=0;

void setup() {
//Set the primary Serial (USB Serial)
Serial.begin(9600);

// Set the pin Serial - known value based on transmitted signal Baud Rate
PEESerial.begin(1200);
}
void loop() {  
// read from port 9 (serial2 Rx) IF there
// is a signal to read.

if (Serial2.available()&& count<6) {
 byteArray[count] = PEESerial.read();
 Serial.println(byteArray[count],HEX);
 Serial.println(byteArray[count],BIN);
 count++;
} 
else {
 count=0;
}  
}
```

Comment: Do you want to store the `7bit` data in each element of the `byteArray`? I am a bit confused what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes that's correct. I am wanting to store them each bit into it's own element of an array. I am going to see if I can't wrap my head around shifting and masking as I believe this may be the only way to extract the bits. I was hoping there was a more simple syntax or method of extraction but some other feedback I've received has eluded to the fact that there is no simple way of extracting bits out of a data byte.

Comment: Your Data will contain a minimum of `8 bits` and the `Most Significant bit` does not affect the data if it is `0`, to ensure that it is `0`, `And` your `byte` with `127` or its binary representation `0b01111111` using the `&` operator. Your statement should look like this: `byteArray[count] = 0b0000000 & yourData`

Comment: I made a typo, can't edit now. Your statement should look like `byteArray[count] = 0b01111111 & yourData` or `byteArray[count] = 127 & yourData`